# C, function not getting called, prototype is there before main()

Tags: c, function

This a HW assignment to copy a file and to check that contents are the same using system calls.

I have a prototype after my include statements:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//three includes to use open
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h> //system calls if sys/syscalls.h does not work
//this give specific error code
#include <errno.h>
extern int errno;

void check_same(char *argv1, char *argv2);
```

Then my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    //mimic fd[0] for read and fd[1] for write
    int fd0, fd1; 
    //return value from read greater than 0 is ok, 0 is EOF, <0 is an error
    int num_bytes;
    //BUFSIZ is 4096 or can be set to 1024, etc but larger is more efficient (bytes)
    char buf[BUFSIZ]; //char *buf for read and write, tracks file pos.
.
.
.
/*function gets called after I copy the file and close the file descriptors*/
if((close(fd1)) <0){
        printf("Write file not closed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

//compare 2 files for sameness
//int same = 0;
check_same(argv[1], argv[2]);

return 0;
}
```

Then the function definition:

```
void check_same(char *argv1, char *argv2){
    printf("in check_same\n");
    //to open files and count bytes read
    int f0, f1, count;
    //position in each file
    int pos1, pos2;
    //buffer size 1 to check each char
    char orig[1];
    char copy[1];
.
.
.
```

The first `printf()` statement does not show on the console so I know it does not even get there.

I have tried changing return type to `int` but get the same result of a successful copy from file `argv[1]` to file `argv[2]` but function `check_same()` not getting called.  What else should I be checking?
For a full reproducible sample, please see comments for a link.

Comment: Put a `\n` at the end of the string and try again. The code probably *does* get there.

Comment: @user3386109 I just tried with same result of successful copy but function not getting called.

Comment: Then the problem is in the `. . .` section of `main`. See [mcve].

Comment: https://ideone.com/GRc3zy @user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you didn’t include in the question, your `if` statement is missing braces:

```
if((write(fd1, buf, num_bytes))!=num_bytes)
    printf("Write error %d\n", num_bytes);
    exit(1);
```

This means it always exits when it gets there.

If you’re using gcc, you can get a warning about this with `-Wall`. (Always pass `-Wall` to your compiler, as a minimum.)